# Stuck on an exercise, for/while loops

Tags: python-3.x, loops, for-loop

New in python and really stuck on this exercise:

> Marvin should ask for a string and print a new string where each character has been incremented by `1` and is separated by `"-"`

Example: input: `"ape"`      output: `"a-pp-eee"`

FYI, it's translated from swedish, if there are any weird wordings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will iterate over the characters of the word and duplicate each entry by its index + 1 (since index is 0 based).  Finally joining the results with '-'

```py
print('-'.join(c * (i + 1) for i, c in enumerate(word)))
```

example:

```
>>> word = 'ape'
>>> print('-'.join(c * (i + 1) for i, c in enumerate(word)))
a-pp-eee
```

without comprehension (to help understand):

```
string_parts = []
for index, character in enumerate(word):
    string_parts.append(character * (index + 1))
print('-'.join(string_parts))
```

Comment: What does "c" mean? Or what does it do?

Comment: c is just a variable that I am using to iterates over each character.  i is the index of each character.  Normally I would use longer more descriptive names, but when they are only used in small `for` loops I punt back to my C naming days, lol

Comment: added an example without using comprehension/generator expression to help understand

Comment: `print('-'.join(c * i for i, c in enumerate(word, start=1)))` might be slightly clearer.